# Sencha Touch : Applying multiple filter to store

Tags: javascript, extjs, sencha-touch-2, store

i want to refresh my list in sencha touch ,based on the multiple selection of my id.

I have implemented filter to my store based on id selected, so when user click on each id the list will be refreshed, code is shown below.

```
control: {
            MaterialscategoryList:{
                itemtap: "refreshList"

        },

refreshList:function (list, index, target, record){

       console.log("record id is " +record.get('id'));
     if(record.get('id') == 1 ){
     Ext.getStore('materialsid').filter('categoryId', '1');
     }else if(record.get('id') == 2 ){
       Ext.getStore('materialsid').filter('categoryId', '2');
     }else if(record.get('id') == 3 ){
       Ext.getStore('materialsid').filter('categoryId', '3');
     }else if(record.get('id') == 4 ){
       Ext.getStore('materialsid').filter('categoryId', '4');
     }else if(record.get('id') == 5 ){
       Ext.getStore('materialsid').filter('categoryId', '5');
     }else if(record.get('id') == 6 ){
       Ext.getStore('materialsid').filter('categoryId', '6');
     }


},
```

I have a scenario where user will select multiple ids and the i want to apply the filter .Not sure how to go ahead. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: You could use a filterFn where you check if the id is in id's of the selected records: http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2.4/2.4.2-apidocs/#!/api/Ext.data.Store-method-filter

Answer (score 0):

```
var store =  Ext.getStore('materialsid');
store.filter(function(record){
   var id =  record.get('categoryId');
   return (id == 1 || id == 2 || id == 3); // you can pass your selected Ids here
});
```